# Max-height and horizontal display with bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adjust the style of my Angular Template using Bootstrap and a personal CSS file.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div static-include="partial/example.html"></div>
```

Here, static-include is a directive I found on Stack Overflow, for not creating a child scope.

```
<!-- example.html -->
<div class="well">
    <h6>Listes</h6>
    <div ng-repeat="column in lists">
        <dt>{{ column.name }}</dt>
        <dd ng-repeat="term in column">{{ term }}</dd>
    </div>
</div>
```

Depending on the $scope used, the size of the div change:

[image: View 1]

But I'd like to be able to specify a max-height. The problem with max-height is that only the size of the well changes :

[image: View 2]

What can I do to declare a max height that if, for example, "Gratuite" goes beyond, it'll be going on the right ?

EDIT: Like this :
[image]

PS: I'm really sorry about the way I'm expressing my problem, but I lack technical vocabulary.

PS2: The last image is photoshopped, I don't have the answer.

Thanks

Comment: would be easier with a jsfiddle - but have you tried `overflow: auto` on the `well`?

Comment: Or a subordinate element if you only want column to scroll.

Comment: try putting a .row around your columns within the well

Comment: The overflow:auto just add a scrollbar, I edited the question adding a picture that might give you a better idea.
Also, adding .row doesn't work =/

Comment: So...  Let me get this straight...  You want your "well" container to wrap horizontally to the right?

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is something like this -> http://masonry.desandro.com/  This library will allow you to float elements to the right within a given container. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a fiddle to replicate your conditions. Perhaps you could fork this and give us a better example of the scenario you are trying to account for?

http://jsfiddle.net/rodhartzell/2AgC4/3/

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="well">
                 <h6>Listes</h6>
                <dl ng-repeat="column in lists"> 
                    <dt>{{ column.name }}</dt>
                    <dl ng-repeat="num in column.term">{{num}}</dl>
                </dl>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

JavaScript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.lists =  [{
            "name": "Peremntion",
            "term": [2, 5, 9, 0, 11, 0, 0]
        }, {
            "name": "column 2",
            "term": [2, 5, 9, 0, 11, 0, 0]
        }];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make your fiddle work =/
The only output I get is 

Listes
{{ column.name }}
    {{ term }}